# How can you write a query that checks the value of a JSON column?

Tags: json, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

Suppose I have a table with three columns: `id`, `name`, `state`. The `state` column is of type `jsonb` and the structure would always have (as a minimum) a key called `active` e.g.

`{"name": "some_name", active: true, ...}`

`{"name": "one_two", active: false, ...}`

I've got everything to work with serializing and deserializing by writing my own `@WritingConverter` and `@ReadingConverter` (to a `PGobject`) and so I could write a query which then at the Java level performs the filter so only those which are 'active' remain.

But how can I, in Spring Data JDBC, write a query that would allow me to interrogate the json column at the level of the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use use the `@Query` annotation and whatever facilities your database offers to query json.

Just as an example this [tutorial for working with JSON in Postgres](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-json/) suggests that something like should work.

```
@Query("select * from mytable where state ->> 'active' = :active ")
List<MyTable> findAllActive(String active)
```

You probably can convert `state ->> 'active'` to something suitable so you can use a `boolean` as the method argument, but I'd start with something simple.

Comment: Thanks this worked. For completeness I'll just add the fully qualified name of @Query: `org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.Query`. And also that I wrote it as `findAllActive(boolean active)` which required changing the query to use `(state ->> 'active') :: boolean = :active`.